# How to create a count down time with Qt?

Tags: qt, qt4.7

All developer could you show me how to create a count down time with c++ Qt? If you can, you should to show me a source code.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) A quick google provides a link to [a document about timers in Qt](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/timers.html) and a link to the [QTimer](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qtimer.html) class.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not the place for us to give you a tutorial. We can however answer practical questions related to problems you face. So try to develop this yourself and should you get stuck, ask a clear question about it including all necessary detail. Then we're more than glad to help.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help ^_^. What i need from you only a cue it's enough for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like that. It calls timeOutSlot every second.

```
#define TIMEOUT 60

...
QTimer * timer = new QTimer();
connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(timeOutSlot()));
timer->start(1000); 
...

void timeOutSlot()
{
    static int time = TIMEOUT;
    time--; // decrement counter
    if (time==0) // countdown has finished
    {
        // timeout
    }
    else // re-start counter
    {
        time->start(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a correct way to do a counter, if the goal is to count down 60 seconds. The timer event will not happen in exactly 1000 ms intervals. QTimer can be used to refresh counter display, but it is not good for counting the actual time. QElapsedTimer is a better class for that.